# ¿Como puedo transformar una imagen que este en el archivo drawble a un Bitmap o a un byte array(byte[])?

Tags: java, android-studio

Quisiera saber como puedo transformar una imagen que tengo en el archivo drawble a un Bitmap o a un arreglos de bytes en codigo java.

**Ejemplo:**

```
Bitmap elBitmap=R.drawble.nombreDelaImagen;
```

**Se que esto en java no se puede pero es un ejemplo para que vean a lo que quiero llegar, quisiera saber si hay algun metodo que pueda usar para poder convertir la imagen guardada del archivo drawble a un bitmap o a un byte[].**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A partir del bitmap puedes obtener un arreglo de bytes de esta forma

```
 //Bitmap elBitmap = R.drawble.nombreDelaImagen;
 Bitmap elBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.nombreDelaImagen);

 ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
 bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, stream);
 byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por ayudarme, el  `.decodeResource` era el metodo que necesitaba pero no sabia que hay estaba.

Comment: Excelente que pudo ser de ayuda mi respuesta, saludos!